# default constructor not invoked

Tags: java, oop, constructor, default-constructor

**Why :**
If a class does not provide any `constructors` then `default constructor(constructor without parameter)` is given by the compiler at the time of compilation but if a class contains `parameterized constructors` then default constructor is not provided by  the compiler.

I am compiling the code below.It gives compilation error.

**Code :**

```
class ConstructorTest
{
    // attributes
    private int l,b;

    // behaviour
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("length="+l);
        System.out.println("breadth="+b);
    }
    public int area()
    {
        return l*b;
    }

    // initialization
    public ConstructorTest(int x,int y) // Parameterized Constructor
    {
        l=x;
        b=y;
    }

    //main method
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        ConstructorTest r = new ConstructorTest(5,10);
        ConstructorTest s = new ConstructorTest();
        s.display();
        r.display();
        r.area();
    }
}
```

**Console Error :**

[image]

When I invoked only `parameterized constructor`. Its working fine.but when want to invoke the `default constructor` with `parameterized constructor`. Compiler gives compilation error as shown in picture.

Any immediate help will be highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Um, so provide your own parameterless constructor - it's as simple as that. The compiler *only* provides a default constructor if you haven't provided one explicitly.

Comment: this is a (pretty much) exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792207/why-does-the-default-parameterless-constructor-go-away-when-you-create-one-with - that should have the info you want

Comment: @JonSkeet, I totally agree with you. I just want to know why ?

Comment: That's just the way the language is defined... If you're asking why the language is designed that way, a lot of your question is redundant.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I just want to know the reason behind this.

Comment: @RohitJindal - You wrote the answer inside the question. Once you provide a parameterized constructor, the compiler does not provide default constructor. You can define a "default" (aka - non parameterized) constructor aside your parameterized constructor.

Comment: @RohitJindal -you follow this question i think this is more useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654167/difference-between-a-no-arg-constructor-and-a-default-constructor-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the paragraph you provided:

> but if a class contains parameterized constructors then default constructor **is not provided** by the compiler.

You have defined a parameterized constructor, therefore the default constructor is not provided by the compiler and therefore must be provided by yourself.

Comment: I agree with you, I want to know why this happen ? if a class contains parameterized constructors then why default constructor is not provided by the compiler ?

Comment: See the linked @Razib posted (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257938/why-is-no-default-constructor-generated-if-you-define-an-explicit-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

If you provides a constructor, then the default constructor is not added to your class. You must define it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error while compiling using `javac ConstructorTest.java`
Because the you declare your parameterized constructor - `public ConstructorTest(int x,int y)`. So compiler doesn't provide any default constructor [`public ConstructorTest()` ] for your class. So you can not call public `ConstructorTest()` at line 28.

Comment: I agree with you, I want to know why this happen ? if a class contains parameterized constructors then why default constructor is not provided by the compiler ?

Comment: @Rohit Jindal, you may see the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046200/why-java-doesnt-provide-default-constructor-if-class-has-parametrized-construc

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you are asking this question. You yourself said "but if a class contains parameterized constructors then default constructor is not provided by the compiler."...so that explains!!

Comment: I agree with you, I want to know why this happen ? if a class contains parameterized constructors then why default constructor is not provided by the compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because this allows one to write a struct such as:

```
struct Test
{ 
    int a;
    double d;
};
```

It doesn't have a constructor.  The user doesn't care if members are initialized.  It is mostly use to contain data.  It can be then be used via:

```
Test t;
```

The end result is less typing.  If one cares about how variables are initialized or the logic to initialize them is out of the ordinary, one writes a constructor.  It is then assumed a default constructor would do something wrong or unintended so it is then not provided.

One could say the same thing about destructors.  If one doesn't care, a default destructor that destroys your members in reverse order and invokes base destructors is provided.  If you override it, then the default one is not produced.